# font sizes of points of x and y axes is large compared to script size

Tags: psfrag

I am using psfrag to convert  eps (converted from figure to eps) to pdf . But in the pdf that is generated, the font size of points of the axes is large and cant be adjusted properly. Please see the image that is attached and suggest me answers.
Thanks...[image]

Comment: It is rather hard to suggest changes to code that you have not shown. As it is all we know is the font is too large so all we can say is to use a smaller font.